# How to stop an application from using port 80

Tags: system

I am trying to free up port 80 for apache2 but it seems python is using it. I want to change this to make apache2 use port 80 without killing 80, is there any other way to stop it or to change the port number for python?

Comment: Do you know which python instance / script is using that port?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I suggest:

First find exactly which instance of python is using it:

```
sudo ss -ap sport == 80 | grep -Po "(?<=pid=).*(?=,)"
```

the above command gives you the PID of process which is listening on port "80".

Then use `ps` to find which parameters has been sent to `python`:

```
ps PID-FROM-ABOVE-COMMAND
```

eg:

```
ps 1462
```

then use same parameters with different port number to run your script/python on another port or change the script/parameters/config files if it was necessary.

Now you have two instance of same program listening on two different port, you can kill the old one and free up the "80" while another instance is listening on another port.

Comment: Ok so I found out the pid number now I just need to know how to change the application using port 80 to a different port number. What is the command for this and how do I find open ports that can be run by the application?

Comment: It's the application which opens a port and it's specific to that program you should read its manual or see the source to find it out.

Comment: Ok well let's say I kill 80 will python2 stop running on it and will apache automatically join 80?

Comment: If no one is listening on 80 so apache can start working and listen on 80. first kill the python process then start the apache.